# Single function for asking and reading input in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, built-in

I am looking for the built-in equivalent of this function:

```
public static string ask(string prompt) {
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I think it is tedious to copy-paste this in every console app, and creating a new class / module just for this tiny utility seems overkill.

---

I ask because the Google search: *c# ask for input and print message in the same line of code* does not give me any meaningful results.

Comment: It is tedious to write these two lines of code, so you would like them to be in a single line? Why not create your own class then? That's why people have "Core" assemblies where they place stuff which is reused between projects. As a side note, [method names in C# are PascalCased by convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: It looks like you've already encapsulated these two lines of code into a single function call.  If calling a function is "too tedious" then perhaps programming isn't really your calling...

Comment: @Groo That is my answer, not a class for just that function, but a class for many utility functions. Very convenient, post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @David :) I mean writing the function down in each module may be tedious, as importing a class just for it would be :)

Comment: control-c control-v ?

Comment: @Joe I do not think that copy-pasting is a good software engineering practice.

Comment: *"I am looking for the built-in equivalent of this function"* It doesn't exist.

Comment: @RonBeyer that should be an answer, being sure that it does not exist is as good as being sure that it exists. I just wanted to be sure that I was not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Caridorc it is already an answer.

Comment: @mariocatch in fact the first part of your answer is good, I downvoted bacause of the second part: _You'll have to get used to writing those two lines of code. It won't take much time, don't worry._ as I may want to use an utility class and not get used to it.

Comment: @Caridorc I'd say that mariocatch's answer, in a round-about way, says the same thing. Accept that one.

Comment: Edited my answer to state the fact about the BCL.

Comment: @David We are here to discuss **ideas** not attack each other, I do not like yours _If calling a function is "too tedious" then perhaps programming isn't really your calling_ also because I never said that calling a function was too tedious for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in shortcut for printing something and then asking for input in the same function.

Comment: @Groo 's idea about a single `Core` class containing all the utilities you want is real cool, much better than writing more code for the same result.

Comment: Yes writing classes to give you functionality is a core component of OOP. However, this type of requested functionality isn't something worth writing a class for in every application you'll write. It's something you typically write a method for if your application uses numerous times... it's not something I'd build into an assembly and reference in future projects.

Comment: Perfect correction that makes this answer coincise and to the point. You may briefly mention a `Core` class to group utility functions just for completeness though. Future visitors will be more happy to be given an alternative.